# Finding the volume of revolution obtained by rotation of a region about the line $2x-y=20$

Tags: multiple-integral, solid-of-revolution

I have the following question before me: Find the volume of the area bounded by the curves $y=x^3$, $x+y=10$ and $x=0$ about the line $2x-y=20$. I started off by drawing the given area and line of rotation. I found out the point of intersection as $(2,8)$. But I do not know how to proceed from there. I tried doing it in terms of perpendicular distances from the line of rotation taking the point $(8,-4)$ as new origin. I obtained this point $(8,-4)$ by drawing a perpendicular on the line of rotation from origin and then finding out the point of intersection of the two lines. But that seemed too daunting a task to me. Is there some (other) nicer method to evaluate this volume? Please suggest. I have shown my work in an attached image.
I have to just set up the double integral and not actually compute it.
[image: Sketch showing the given area and computation of point of intersection]

Comment: Try $\int_0^8 y^{\frac{1}{3}} dx + \int_8^{10} 10-y dx$.

Comment: @Tchills That will only give us the area bounded by the curves $y=x^3$ , $x+y=10$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Indeed ... can you use theorem of Pappus? Rotate the area about the axis ..provided it's  in its own plane... get the centroid distances of the above areas and  use $V =2 \pi ×A ×c.$ where c is the total distance moved by the centroids of the two areas.

Comment: @Tchills One can definitely find the volume of this solid of revolution by using Pappus Theorem. But I have to set this volume up a double integral. How can I do that?

Comment: You should first use rotation of coordinate axes so x-axis is parallel to $2x-y = 20$. From there on, it is straightforward to set up double integral to find volume of rotation.

Comment: @HARVEER RAWAT in relation to the use of rotation of the  axes..one could rotate the x-axis through $tan^{-1}(2)$  to line up with the axis of rotation.Then simply transform the limits using $x_1=x_0cos (tan^ {-1}(2)) + y_0sin (tan^{-1}(2))$ and $y_1=-x_0sin (tan^{-1}(2))+y_0cos(tan^{-1}(2))$. I think that now you can find the correct centroids using the new limits.